# Auto delete line

Tags: excel, row, lines

I have create a table of Different Operators, handling different Vessel and having different code. I want to be able to auto delete the table based on the 1 Operator on each worksheet (which I have used Macro to copy paste on each individual sheet). What kind of formula can I use to auto delete the table lines in order to keep the data of the individual Operators on different worksheet?

```
OPS    | VES NAME              | CODE
CMAN     CMA CGM VELA CRUZ       017
CMANS    CMA CGM EXPRESS         018
GRAND    NYK ORPHEUS             036
MSCO     MSC HEIDI               109
CMAN     CMA CGM HYDRA           009
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel, try selecting the table, then `Insert | PivotTable` and you will be able to hide the table lines for all but the operators that interest you at any given moment.